# While loop doesn't run a indexOf search

Tags: java, string, indexof

I'm trying to find out how many times one string appears in another. For my testing, I'm using "ea" for wordOne and "Ilikedthebestontheeastbeachleast" for wordTwo. My output is returning 0 for my "appearance" variable, which should store how many times "ea" appears in wordTwo.

Here's the relevant code section:

```
int wordTwoLength = wordTwo.length();
  System.out.println(wordTwoLength);

  while (wordTwoLength > 0)
  {
     positionCount = wordTwo.indexOf(wordOne, positionCount);
     appearances = appearances++;
     wordTwoLength = (wordTwoLength - positionCount);
  }
  System.out.println(appearances);
```

Comment: Why doesn't that work?

Comment: unit test, debug using IDE. What have you tried/

Comment: We haven't learned about unit test IDE in class. my final print statement just returns 0. No errors, but it doesn't give the output I expect, which is 3.

Comment: After fixing the appearance++ thing it's now returning 2 instead of 3. I tried initializing positionCount to 1 instead of 0, but still get the same return of 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong output from a while loop using indexOf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395447/wrong-output-from-a-while-loop-using-indexof)

Comment: OK, I have edited my answer so that it deals with both your bugs, rather than just the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by

```
 appearances = appearances++;
```

This will make sure appearances is ZERO always.

Shouldn't it be just appearances++ ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you set the value of appearances.  There's a difference between

```
appearances = appearances++;
```

and

```
appearances = ++appearances;
```

What you have will assign the value of appearances and then increment the 'old' appearances variable.  You're going to want to increment it and then assign it.

Alternatively, you could just write

```
appearances++;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs here.

One is that you've written `appearances = appearances++;` instead of just `appearances++;`.  The effect of this is that `appearances` is incremented, and then reset to its previous value; in other words, there's no change.

The second bug is that you're beginning each search after the first, at the location where the match was found.  So you're just finding the same match over and over.  Your output will just therefore depend on how many times you can subtract `positionCount` before `wordTwoLength` becomes negative.

Here is how I would write this method, if I had to.

```
public int numberOfOccurrences(String toExamine, String toFind) {
    int currentPosition = 0;
    int occurrences = 0;

    for(;;) {
       int index = toExamine.indexOf(toFind, currentPosition);
       if (index == -1) {
           return occurrences;
       }
       currentPosition = index + toFind.length();
       occurrences++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Any idea why it would output 2 instead of 3 for appearance? I thought it was an issue with the initialization of my positionCount variable to 0, so I changed it to 1, but still get the same output.

Comment: You're just finding the first "ea" each time.  You're setting `positionCount` to the wrong thing.  Try it with the debugger and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be your problem. The line "appearances = appearances++;" will, in your case,  set appearances to 0. This is because the ++ operator increments the variable but returns the original number. You just want to put "appearances++;".

I.e. it takes appearances (which is 0) adds 1 to it (making its value 1)and then returns 0. So basically the statement is equivalent to "appearances = 0;".